# CSS3 - hover from one div into another

Tags: html, css, hover, nested

I can't figure out how to or is it even possible, to change one div's child's attributes when hovering over other div's child.

Here is the example.
http://jsfiddle.net/0m0468f6/3/

```
<div id='bigdiv1'>
<div id='smalldiv1'></div>
</div>
<div id='bigdiv2'>
<div id='smalldiv2'></div>
</div>

#smalldiv1:hover~#smalldiv2{
background:yellow;}
```

More precisely, how to change one div's attributes hovering over another, while the two of those are located separately in two wrappers.
Is it possible with only css3, and if not - is there any other way to style the html.

Comment: I afraid you can't. Only with JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/0m0468f6/4/)

I've used `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events.

**HTML**

```
<div id='bigdiv1'>
    <div id='smalldiv1' onmouseover="chbg('yellow')" onmouseout="chbg('green')">
    </div>
</div>
<div id='bigdiv2'>
    <div id='smalldiv2'>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function chbg(color) {
    document.getElementById('smalldiv2').style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In css it is only possible to change the attribute of child elements or itself.

```
#bigdiv2:hover #smalldiv2{
    background:yellow;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0m0468f6/7/

In this html structure i would do it with JavaScript.

```
var smalldiv1 = document.getElementById('smalldiv1');
var smalldiv2 = document.getElementById('smalldiv2');

smalldiv1.onmouseover = function(event){
    smalldiv2.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
};

smalldiv1.onmouseout = function(event){
    smalldiv2.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0m0468f6/8/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use a #wrapper element and you need to support only modern browser, a pure css solution could involve `pointer-events` and `clip-path` properties

http://jsfiddle.net/kmao8uk2/4/

The CSS inserted is

```
#wrapper { position: relative; }

#smalldiv1 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#smalldiv2 {
    padding-top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    padding-top: 200px;
    z-index: 1;

    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 33%, 0 33%, 
         0 66%, 100% 66%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 33%, 0 33%, 0 66%, 
         100% 66%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);    

}


#smalldiv2:hover {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

I changed the size of your `#smalldiv2` so now it is 300px tall, but thanks to `clip-path` its shape is empty in the red part.

As a result `#smalldiv1` covers `#smalldiv2` but when you hover the first one, the `cursor-pointer` property so defined will pass the `hover` event to the elements underlying, so it's like you're actually hovering `#smalldiv2`.

Comment: I am pretty amazed by the solution you worked out and it's something I'm glad I learned, and I assume that means there is no solution for my problem without this kind of 'illusion' trick? I'd like to know if its possible to affect the smalldiv2 via smalldiv1 using *hover*? I guess no?

Comment: well no, this trick is a workaround for it (if you want use only css of course)

Comment: yea i am indeed aiming for pure css, and this trick of yours is quite nice, i'm sure i'll play around with it and hope to get max out of it, thanks alot! :)